# How to align the Grid to the height of the video player?

Tags: css, css-position, overlay

I have a Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dyrepk2x/494/

```
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
      <div class="video-overlay">
        <div id="gridLayout">
              <div class="box1 box" slot="1">1</div>
              <div class="box2 box" slot="2">2</div>
              <div class="box3 box" slot="3">3</div>
              <div class="box4 box" slot="4">4</div>
              <div class="box5 box" slot="5">5</div>
              <div class="box6 box" slot="6">6</div>
              <div class="box7 box" slot="7">7</div>
              <div class="box8 box" slot="8">8</div>
              <div class="box9 box" slot="9">9</div>
              <div class="box10 box" slot="10">10</div>
              <div class="box11 box" slot="11">11</div>
              <div class="box12 box" slot="12">12</div>
              <div class="box13 box" slot="13">13</div>
              <div class="box14 box" slot="14">14</div>
              <div class="box15 box" slot="15">15</div>
  </div>
  </div>
        <video id="player" controls
    src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" autoplay loop></video>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.outer-container {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.inner-container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.video-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#gridLayout{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.box{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    width: 16.666%;
    position: relative;z-index: 0;
    height: 16.666%;
}
```

I want the 6x6 grid to fit as an overlay to the size of the video element using CSS, it should be responsive too, how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Update Code**](https://jsfiddle.net/cnsvnc/dyrepk2x/497/)

you can see this updated. you should use it inner border for full width box. like `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);` and no padding , no margin `.video-overlay`

Comment: i dunno which answer to accept, ill add it to my project and let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

After tweaking the `#gridLayout` CSS a little along with the `.video-overlay` I then tweaked the width of the `.box` to match up with the video at different screen sizes, you can see the updated [**FIDDLE HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/dyrepk2x/495/).

Let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much, i wish i could accept both answers, but there seems to be a small space left at the bottom of the grid in your code.